# Dialog Scrim Is Not Shown In Emulator

Tags: android, kotlin, android-emulator, android-alertdialog, android-xml

I have a problem in my emulator. My emulator is not shown AlertDialog Scrim. I don't know why. I was try to reset my emulator, changing API level but not solve problem. How can I solve?

Number 5 is Scrim

[image: What is Scrim]

There is an example for comparing.
My emulator like right but real device like left

[image: There is an example]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These steps should enable the *Dialog Scrim/Dim/Fade*

> 1. Turn on your emulator/device **Developer Options;**
> 2. Scroll down to the section **'Hardware accelerated rendering';**
> 3. Then, just enable the **'Disable HW overlays'.**

Any question about **Developer Options**, refer to this documentation: **[Enable Developer options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#enable)**

[image: Disable HW Overlays]

Comment: Google Developer tools are a joke at this point. I debugged my themes for hours. It's getting worse every year

Comment: Because of AI, each of the communities is running slower. Also, you know, debugging can be challenging, especially when it seems like things are getting more complicated over time.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that encounters this same issue. This is a known issue with Android Studio if your emulator version is on: 33.1.13

Check out https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/289117017?pli=1 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I found way for this issue. I explained in here step by step:

- First, we have to enter `%LOCALAPPDATA%`
- And then, we have to enter `Android -> Sdk`
- In here, we can see `emulator` folder
- We need to delete this folder
- Then we can retry to install in `Android Studio`
- Start emulator in `Device Manager`
- We have a warning. In this moment click `OK`
- We need to wait finish `SDK Component Installer`
- It will automatically reboot when completed.

[image: Before-After]