# Android 14 outside of AlertDialog doesn't get dim

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

On Android 14 Upside-down cake emulator, when showing an alert dialog, outside of alert dialog doesn't get dim. How can I get dim just like other android versions?

[image]

[image]

I tried:

```
alertDialog.window?.setDimAmount(0.7f)
```

But only Android 14 doesn't work.
Thank you.

Comment: got this problem on emulator, can't resolve it yet.

Comment: Hope this will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77610325/16411959

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have same problem on emulator.But when i switch on disable HW overlays in develop options ,the dim shows again , and i don't know why.

I guess it is emulator cause the problem. I tested the real device and the emulator, only the emulator does not show dim.

Same problem on issue tracker

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/289117017

Comment: Thank you sir, i tried this on my emulator with api 29 on my windows machine, the shadow behind the dialog automatically show