# Android 14 - bottomsheet dialog transparent background

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

I have the following attributes for bottom sheet dialog:

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/RoundedBottomSheet</item>
    <style name="RoundedBottomSheet" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/popup_window_enter_animation</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/popup_window_exit_animation</item>
    </style>
```

In Versions under android 14 I see the dim background by default, but on android 14 I don't see any dim, the background is transparent.
How to add the dim?

I tried to add this but it doesn't work

```
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
```

Comment: Is this only on emulators or also on real devices? The emulator-only problem has been described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76641510/android-14-outside-of-alertdialog-doesnt-get-dim

Answer (score 1):

Apart from adding:

```
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
```

Could you also add the following line after it, in order to define the Dim Amount:

```
<item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.5</item>
```

It's an adjustable floating value ranging from 0.0 (no dim) to 1.0 (completely opaque).

Comment: thanks, but still doesn't work

Comment: That's strange. What if you try to separate the Dialog style and Rounded bottom sheet in separate sections?